# TypeError: Unable to get property 'project' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to angular js here and I am facing this issue (maybe a simple one but as I a beginner I have no idea why this is happening). I am always getting the below error when I try to assign some value to my $scope for model. One of them is as follows.

HTML code,

```
<input type="text" id="StartDate" class="col-sm-2" ng-model="project.StartDate" />
```

Angular function code,

```
function DateUpdate($scope) {
    debugger;
    $scope.project.StartDate = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
}
DateUpdate();
```

and I am getting error like,

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'project' of undefined or null reference
```

Appreciate the help as I am stuck with this error in a lot of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the `$scope.project` as an empty object first.

One way to do is

```
$scope.project = {}
$scope.project.StartDate = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

or you can do like this

```
$scope.project = { 
    'StartDate' : new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
}
```

and when you call the function remove the `scope` as a parameter also

```
function  DateUpdate(){
```

Comment: already tried that. but unfortunately that didnt work either.

Comment: myApp.controller('ProjectCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'fileUpload', '$filter', function ($scope, $http, $filter, APICall, fileUpload)
{
        
    $scope.formsubmit = function () {
        //code here
    }

    function DateUpdate($scope) {
        debugger;
        var c = new Date();
        $scope.project.StartDate = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
    }
    DateUpdate();

    $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        //code here
    };

    $scope.fetchDetails = function () {

        //code here
}
]);

Comment: @Aneez  replace the controller with this `myApp.controller('ProjectCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'APICall', 'fileUpload'function($scope, $http, $filter, APICall, fileUpload) {
    $scope.formsubmit = function() {}

    function DateUpdate() {
        var c = new Date();
        $scope.project = {
            'StartDate': new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
        }
    }
    DateUpdate();
    $scope.uploadFile = function() {};
    $scope.fetchDetails = function() {}


}]);`

Comment: Bingo!! that worked. thanks a lot. then this should be the way I should be using everywhere. :)

Comment: yep always make sure `function($scope, $http, $filter, APICall, fileUpload)` follow the same order as string injections `['$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'APICall', 'fileUpload',`. like this `myApp.controller('ProjectCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'APICall', 'fileUpload', function($scope, $http, $filter, APICall, fileUpload) {`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `DateUpdate` function parameter `$scope` which kills existance of existing `$scope`, and `$scope` becomes `undefined` inside function

```
function DateUpdate() { //<-- remove `$scope` which isn't required at all.
```

Comment: TypeError: Unable to set property 'StartDate' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @Aneez as sachila already suggested, you have to define `$scope.project = "{}`  before accessing startdate property from it. check his 1st suggested option..